# Bearer client of keycloak with client secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

Keycloak has 3 different clients: public, confidential and bearer.

I understand that bearer clients cannot obtain tokens and it is mainly for verification. But what confusing me is in keycloak, the bearer client can have a client secret, in which possible scenario can the client secret of a bearer can be used?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911507/keycloak-bearer-only-clients-why-do-they-exist)?

Comment: Hello @KoheiTAMURA, yes, I saw that post. but they didn't explain how to use client secret of a bearer client (service b).. when service b is verifying the token (given by service A) with keycloak, it doesn't require client secret. I was thinking that there might be a configuration that it will require service b to pass a client secret upon verifying the token with keycloak, and this is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Did you find an answer for that? Asking myself the same thing.

Comment: Hi @MarioB, nope, was not  able to get an answer for this one :)